# How to change the apacite citation style to list only "first author et al." for entries with three or more authors

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, apa-style

I need to change the format of my bibliography in order to have one author or at maximum two authors. I use `bibtex` and the `\bibliographystyle{apacite}`. Sometimes the citations are reported as "first author et al.", but the majority of times the citations are very long with up to five or six authors.

I overrode the default `apacite.bst` by creating a new `myapacite.bst`. Then, I modified the lines of the function `authors.reflist.apa6` from #7 to #2. Finally, I copied this file both inside the directory of `main.tex` and inside the directory `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/apacite` (Ubuntu 14.04) and I updated the database with `sudo -H mktexlsr`.

As last thing, I changed my bibliography style

```
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{myapacite}
```

Unfortunately, I does not work. I searched a lot without finding a solution. What I missing?

Comment: You should not touch upon `texmf-dist\ `. On updating your distribution, your modification might be overwritten. Any personal file, modification, &c., of general usage should be in `texmf-local\ `. Now you might consider using `\biblatex-apa`, as it is a simple option(`[maxcitenames=xx, mincitenames=yy]` on loading biblatex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than modify the file `apacite.bst`, you could use the command `\shortcite` -- provided by the [apacite](http://ctan.org/pkg/apacite) package -- instead of `\cite`; the macro `\shortcite` generates "firstauthor et al" callouts for all entries with three or more authors.

If you want *all* citation callouts to be of the short form throughout the document, without replacing all `\cite` commands with `\shortcite`, you could insert the instruction

```
\let\cite\shortcite
```

in the preamble of your document, after loading `apacite`. That way, you can use `\cite` in the body of the document but get the citation callouts in the `\shortcite` form.