# How to make apacite typeset 'et al.' for all entries with 3 or more authors in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, apacite, author

The question that is closest to this one is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185884/how-to-change-the-apacite-citation-style-to-list-only-first-author-et-al-for). The simplest solution is to use `\shortcite` provided in the `apacite` package. However, `\shortcite` is treated as an unknown command when I compile it alongside beamer.

These are my loaded packages:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation (avoids badboxes)
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} % Math packages
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{algorithm, algorithmic}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{gensymb} % \degree symbol
\usepackage{color}
```

This is where the references are displayed

```
\subsection{Bibliography}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}
\tiny
%\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{GaitAnalysis}
\end{frame}
```

Why isn't `\shortcite` working? Is there any other alternative solution to the problem?

Comment: Can you consider using `biblatex-apa`?

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407)? If I use your code fragments with a random bib entry and `\cite`, I get "et al." in the text and "..." in the bibliography.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When  you load `apacite` with the `natbibapa` option it does not implement the extended citation commands that `apacite` uses. So the `\shortcite` command is not available, only the `natbib` supplied citation commands.

Unfortunately `natbib` takes a different approach to this, and assumes that the short version is the default, and only provides citation commands to force the long version, but not the other way around.

So the simplest solution to your problem is to load `apacite` *without* the `natbibapa` option.

```
% !BIB TS-program = bibtex

\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{TestCite2000,
    Author = {Smith, R. and Jones, O. and Doe, J and Yang, X. and Silva, E.},
    Journal = {A Great Predatory Journal},
    Title = {A title},
    Volume = {3},
    Year = {2000}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[]{apacite}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A citation}
\shortcite{TestCite2000}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{References}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you so much; this answer completely solved the problem. Just some few points to note: I used `natbib` just for the `\citep` command. After removing `natbibapa`, the plain `\cite` did the same job in `apacite` package, and `\shortcite` and its derivatives started to work without a glitch.

Comment: How can I display upto two authors, then only et al using apacite ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a shortcite using the package  \usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

Check the apacite package documentation: https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/apacite/apacite.pdf

"There is no separate command for the short author list, but it can be obtained with the construction \shortcites{key}\citet{key}"