# How to resize reference fonts in beamer when using apacite?

Tags: beamer, fonts, bibliographies, apacite

The reference section in beamer spans too many slides in my case so I would like to reduce it's font size to bring it down to less than 7 slides.

This is start of the `latex` file:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation (avoids badboxes)
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} % Math packages
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{algorithm, algorithmic}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{gensymb} % \degree symbol
```

This is the reference section:

```
\section{References}
\subsection{Bibliography}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{GaitAnalysis}
\end{frame}
```

There are quite a few posts related to this in TeX.SE, so I'll list out what I tried.

1. Using the shrink option (as done [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249059/adjust-texts-size-in-beamer-when-bibliography-is-too-long)) as `shrink=90` along with `allowframebreaks` makes the reference section become mysteriously invisible.
2. Using `\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\scriptsize}` as shown in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57177/beamer-changing-the-font-size-of-the-references-using-the-shrink-argument-cause) requires the use of `biblatex`. So I tried adding `\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}` to the list of packages. However, it clashed with the `apacite` package and removing which prevents me from using the `\shortcite` command.
3. I also tried adding these lines (as prescribed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283271/77071))

   `\setbeamerfont{bibliography item}{size=\footnotesize}
   \setbeamerfont{bibliography entry author}{size=\footnotesize}
   \setbeamerfont{bibliography entry title}{size=\footnotesize}
   \setbeamerfont{bibliography entry location}{size=\footnotesize}
   \setbeamerfont{bibliography entry note}{size=\footnotesize}`

   But there was no change to the reference font at all.
4. This is what I used to do when using IEEEtran reference style ([ref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/343/77071))

   `{\footnotesize
   \bibliography{bibfile}}`

   which used to work so well, but it has no effect when using `apacite`; I don't know what is preventing it from working now.
5. As I cannot use `natbib` (due to the conflict with `apacite`) I cannot use [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1442/77071) solution either: `\def\bibfont{\footnotesize}`

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As you did not provide compilable code, I took the example from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366791/36296

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{TestCite2000,
    Author = {Smith, R. and Jones, O. and Doe, J and Yang, X. and Silva, E.},
    Journal = {A Great Predatory Journal},
    Title = {A title},
    Volume = {3},
    Year = {2000}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[]{apacite}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A citation}
\shortcite{TestCite2000}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{References}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\renewcommand{\bibliographytypesize}{\tiny}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! This solved my problem. I spent a whole day trying to get the look as above; thanks a lot. Just for curiosity's sake, why did pt. no. 4 didn't work for me when I switched from IEEETran.bst?

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac If you look into the documentation of `apacite` it says that `\bibliographytypesize` is used at the beginning of the reference list and its default value is `\normalssize` -- this will simply overwrite your size commands used before, its like writing `{\footnotesize\normalsize\bibliography{bibfile}}`